LIBCURL ERROR when connecting to GCP ODBC
127     if driver_name == 'GCP':
128         return pyodbc.connect('DSN=GCP', autocommit=True)
130     return pyodbc.connect('DSN={}'.format(driver_name))
131 except pdDatabaseError as e:

Error: ('HY000', '[HY000] [Simba][BigQuery] (1101) LibcURL error: A requested feature, protocol or option was not found built-in in this libcurl due to a build-time decision. (1101) (SQLDriverConnect); [HY000] [Simba][BigQuery] (1101) LibcURL error: A requested feature, protocol or option was not found built-in in this libcurl due to a build-time decision. (1101)')

I keep getting this error trying to query a GCP table through the Simba ODBC, any ideas why?
I've tried uninstalling pycurl and re installing as well ay pyodbc.

If you are running your code on Linux, try connecting via unixODBC's isql command-line utility and see if that works.
